# Как изменять содержимое элементов карточек в RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Для практики делаю подобие аудио плеера.

У меня есть RecyclerView с карточками песен, в каждой из которых отображается кнопка (play/pause), SeekBar для трекинга и два TextView с названием и оставшимся временем.
В отдельном потоке реализован код для ежесекундного обновления положения seekbar'а и оставшегося времени.

Когда я запускаю трек, при скроллинге обнаруживаю, что поток также обрабатывает параллельно и какие-то другие песни.

Подозреваю, что ошибка в том, что, например, для изменения текста времени я обращаюсь к объекту TextView во ViewHolder. Если я правильно понял из прочитанного, адаптер, создав объект ViewHolder для карточки, может использовать этот же объект viewHolder'а для заполнения уже другой карточки, если первоначальная ушла далеко из видимости.

```
viewHolder.audioTime.setText(...);
```

Возможно ли получить и хранить ссылки на объекты одного трека?
Как сделать, чтобы прогресс отображался только для проигрываемой песни?

Answer (score 1):

Постараюсь продемонстрировать на простом примере. `RecyclerView`, который вызывает `notifyItemChanged(position)` если карточка номер `position` была кликнута пользователм.

Код Активности для примера:

```
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class HelloActivity extends Activity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new HelloAdapter());
        DefaultItemAnimator animator = new DefaultItemAnimator() {
            @Override
            public boolean canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(animator);
    }

    private static class HelloAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HelloAdapter.HelloViewHolder> {

        public class HelloViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public TextView textView;

            public HelloViewHolder(CardView cardView) {
                super(cardView);
                textView = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public HelloViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            CardView cardView = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
            return new HelloViewHolder(cardView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(HelloViewHolder holder, int position) {
            bind(holder);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 20;
        }

        private void bind(final HelloViewHolder holder) {
            holder.textView.setText("item " + holder.getAdapterPosition());
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                    Log.d("butt", "click " + position);
                    HelloAdapter.this.notifyItemChanged(position);
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Вызов `notifyItemChanged(int)` вызывает перерисовку измененного элемента. 
То есть Вам нужно будет:

1. В класс `Song` добавить поле `progress` типа int.
2. Поле `progress` для всех песен, кроме проигрываемой держать в значении -1.
3. По мере проигрывания песни изменять значение `progress` от 0 до 100%.
4. При каждом изменении вызывать `adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)`, где `position` - номер песни в списке.
5. Не забывать вызывать `adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)` при выборе новой песни и для старой песни (которая прекратила проигрывание) и для новой (запущенной).
6. Отрисовка карточки в адаптере (`SeekBar`) зависит от значения поля `progress` соответствующей песни.

Ссылки:

[Документация на notifyItemChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged(int))

[Схожий вопрос на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176336/need-an-example-about-recyclerview-adapter-notifyitemchangedint-position-objec)

P.s. Так как песни, я полагаю, у Вас хранятся в списке, `position` Вы можете брать просто как индекс в списке, должно работать. Изменять состояние элементов можно там же, список - он один для адаптера и Вашей активности / фрагмента.